# I am getting different results when using 'Maximize on play '?

Tags: unity, physics, input

so i'll be straight to point.
when i move my character without using 'max on play' it works fine just as i wanted it to be.
but when i switch to 'max on play' my character moves very fast.
i am using `addForce()` to make me character move in `Update()`.

after some googling i found that as i am working with physics i need to use `FixedUpdate();`
But when i tried with fixed update i felt like it was not registering the keystrokes as it would in `Update()`.
i would really appreciate if someone would help me out here.

**Edit - Movement Script Added**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float jump_speed;
    [SerializeField] float walk_speed;
    [SerializeField] float max_speed;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    int jump_counter;
    Animator animator;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        jump_counter = 0;      
        animator.SetBool("isIdle", true);
        animator.SetBool("isWalkingLeft", false);
        animator.SetBool("isWalkingRight", false);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)  && jump_counter <=1)
        {
            rb.AddForce(transform.up * jump_speed);
            jump_counter++;
        }
       else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            rb.AddForce(transform.right * walk_speed);
            PlayWalkingRightAnimation();
        }
       else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            rb.AddForce(-transform.right * walk_speed);
            PlayWalkingLeftAnimation();
        }
        else
        {
            if(jump_counter<=0) PlayIdleAnimation();
        }
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
{
     rb.velocity = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(rb.velocity, max_speed);

}
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        jump_counter = 0;
    }
   
    void PlayWalkingLeftAnimation()
    {
        animator.SetBool("isWalkingLeft", true);
        animator.SetBool("isWalkingRight", false);
        animator.SetBool("isIdle", false);
    }
    void PlayWalkingRightAnimation()
    {
        animator.SetBool("isWalkingRight", true);
        animator.SetBool("isWalkingLeft", false);
        animator.SetBool("isIdle", false);
    }
    void PlayIdleAnimation()
    {
        animator.SetBool("isWalkingLeft", false);
        animator.SetBool("isWalkingRight", false);
        animator.SetBool("isIdle", true);
    }

}
```

I have added whole script hope this helps understand my problems.

Comment: If you want help troubleshooting a problem in your code, you'll need to show us your code. There are dozens of common mistakes you might be making, but we can only tell you which ones they are if you show us in detail what you're doing.

Comment: sorry, ill update the post with code right away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for the problem. also i am not sure if its a good thing to do.

what i did essentially was limit my framerate in the game by using these two lines in

```
void Awake()
    {
        QualitySettings.vSyncCount = 0;
        Application.targetFrameRate = framerate;// i've set it to 60;
    }
```

after implementing this, it seems pretty much same on both maximize on play and normal game view.

Comment: This means your game simulation is framerate-dependent. You should fix that root problem, not mask the symptoms by locking the framerate. Otherwise the problem will come back as soon as a player tries to run your game on a weaker device that drops below your target 60 fps.

Comment: that's exactly what i want but i cant find a proper solution. still looking for one

Answer (score 0):

To register KeyStrokes you need to Do it in Update().

And All the Physics related calculation in thee Fixed Update

Here's a sample Code

```
 private void Update()
{

//Register Key Strokes

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("a"))
    {
        MoveLeft();
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown("d"))
    {
        MoveRight();
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    //Player Movement
        _rb.velocity=(Vector3.forward*playerSpeed)*Time.deltaTime;
        
}//Fixed Update


void MoveLeft()
{
    transform.position=new Vector3(transform.position.x-1,transform.position.y,transform.position.z);// snappy
}//Move Left

void MoveRight()
{
    transform.position=new Vector3(transform.position.x+1 ,transform.position.y,transform.position.z);//snappy
    
}//Move Right
```

Hope this Helps

Comment: i have updated the post by adding code i am currently using which is causing  me issues.
and thank you for your reply definitely try it.

Comment: ok just realized, i have tried with directly changing the position of character using transform.position but i get weird collision problems, so someone from the same forum suggested using addforce() and worked out pretty well for me.

Comment: That's nice. It worked Finally

Comment: no no, you misunderstood me, i am still facing the issue. the code you suggested directly teleports the object to the given co-ords, which gives me colliding issues.(stuttery effect)

Comment: Oh sorry, So In the Moving Function just use `Time.deltaTime`